# How to remove previously mapped field with changeing key name in json in mule dataweave

Tags: mule, transform, message, dataweave

this is my input

> `[{   "eventType": "ORDER_SHIPPED",   "entityId":
>   "d0594c02-fb0e-47e1-a61e-1139dc185657",   "userName":
>   "educator@school.edu",    "dateTime": "2010-11-11T07:00:00Z",     "status":
>   "SHIPPED",    "additionalData": {         "quoteId":
>   "d0594c02-fb0e-47e1-a61e-1139dc185657",       "clientReferenceId":
>   "Srites004",      "modifiedDt": "2010-11-11T07:00:00Z",       "packageId":
>   "AIM_PACKAGE",        "sbsOrderId": "TEST-TS-201809-79486",
>         "orderReferenceId": "b0123c02-fb0e-47e1-a61e-1139dc185987",
>         "shipDate_1": "2010-11-11T07:00:00Z",           "shipDate_2":
>   "2010-11-12T07:00:00Z",           "shipDate_3": "2010-11-13T07:00:00Z",
>         "shipMethod_1": "UPS Ground","shipMethod_3": "UPS Ground3",
>                 "shipMethod_2": "UPS Ground2", "trackingNumber_3": "333",       "trackingNumber_1": "2222",         "trackingNumber_2": "221"}
>
> }]`

the expected output is to remove key name similar like shipdate,tracking number,shipmethod. it  can range from shipdate_1 to n.

{
           "attribute_name": {
             "quoteId": "d0594c02-fb0e-47e1-a61e-1139dc185657",
             "clientReferenceId": "Srites004",
             "modifiedDt": "2010-11-11T07:00:00Z",
             "packageId": "AIM_PACKAGE",
             "sbsOrderId": "TEST-TS-201809-79486",
             "orderReferenceId": "b0123c02-fb0e-47e1-a61e-1139dc185987",
             "shipDate_1": "2010-11-11T07:00:00Z", -to be removed
             "shipDate_2": "2010-11-12T07:00:00Z", -to be removed
             "shipDate_3": "2010-11-13T07:00:00Z", -to be removed
           "shipMethod_1": "UPS Ground", -to be removed
             "shipMethod_3": "UPS Ground3", -to be removed
             "shipMethod_2": "UPS Ground2", -to be removed
             "trackingNumber_3": "333", -to be removed
             "trackingNumber_1": "2222", -to be removed
             "trackingNumber_2": "221" -to be removed
         }

Answer (score 1):

You can use `mapObject` operator to iterate over keys and filter out keys you want to exclude. Something like

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json skipNullOn="everywhere"
---
attribute_name : payload.additionalData[0] mapObject {
    (($$) : $) when  not ( ($$ contains "shipDate") or ($$ contains "shipMethod") or ($$ contains "trackingNumber") )
 }
```

**Update:** for dynamic field names
Define property like

```
property.field.name=shipDate,shipMethod,trackingNumber
```

**Updated Code:-**

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json skipNullOn="everywhere"
%var fields = p("property.field.name") splitBy ","
%function checkField(key)  (sizeOf (fields filter (key contains $))) == 0
---
attribute_name : payload.additionalData[0] mapObject {
    (($$) : $) when checkField($$) 
 }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: this works fine but can we call those fields from property file

Comment: yes. You can call these fields from properties file like `p("property.field.name")`

Comment: I am getting some error while calling from property file..can u please give me sample code that would be more helpfull

Comment: It will be more easy to help if you post tried code along with error rather than mentioning some error. Define property with comma separated field then fetch it while mapping. Use the same for filtering. I have updated answer for more details.

Comment: but im getting all the fields  in updated code
thank you for your response

Comment: if property value is null or blank it will fetch all fields.I have tested with `%dw 1.0
%output application/json skipNullOn="everywhere"
%var fields = "shipDate,shipMethod,trackingNumber" splitBy ","
%function checkField(key)  (sizeOf (fields filter (key contains $))) == 0
---
attribute_name : payload.additionalData[0] mapObject {
    (($$) : $) when checkField($$) 
 }` . It works fine.

Comment: This works fine. but i cant able to fetch from property file.

Comment: %var fields1 = p("property1")  splitBy  ","

Comment: [This article](https://dzone.com/articles/mulesoft-dataweave-language-reading-properties-fro) will help you to load and use properties in dataweave.